# IBM IoT Raspberry Pi Connection refused not authorized

Tags: raspberry-pi3, node-red, watson-iot

I have been using a Raspberry Pi 3 along with IBM Watson IoT platform and was just deploying some flows. However, I think I may have mixed up the device id between Gateway and Device.

When I registered my Raspberry Pi as a Device and a Gateway, I gave both connections the same Device ID. In hindsight, I can see why this might have been stupid. I am just going to disconnect all connections and create two new connections. However, I have a different problem right now. Whenever I try to launch NodeRed from my Raspberry Pi, I get the following log

```
3 Feb 17:07:27 - [error] IBMIoT: Error: Connection refused: Not authorized
[BaseClient:connect] Iotfclient is offline. Retrying connection
[BaseClient:onClose] Connection was closed.
```

This just keeps repeating over and over again, and I have no idea what to do to fix it.

Comment: What happens if you go into the IoT dashboard and change on of the ids (or delete and recreate with different id)

Comment: I already tried doing that. Initially I was getting a different error, about some file or object not existing. When I removed the devices and added new ones, that went away and was replaced with the error message I have listed above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That suggests you still have an IoT node in your flow with the incorrect credentials.

Assuming you are running Node-RED 0.15 or later, open the search dialog (Ctrl-. on 0.15 or Ctrl-F on 0.16) and search for `ibmiot`. That will reveal any existing configuration nodes you have. Clicking on one in the search results will reveal it in the Config node sidebar tab. Double click on it and either delete it or correct the credentials.

If you're on an older version (I suggest you upgrade), you can open the config node sidebar from the dropdown menu and manually look for the `ibmiot` nodes.